# How to fix 'Expression: vector subscript out of range' error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I'm in the process of making a simple game via SFML and have encountered the following error:

**Debug assertation failed!
Expression: vector subscript out of range**

This error only appears when the 'rocket' makes contact with the first 'enemy' whilst there are 3 enemies on screen at the same time.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++) //This is where the error points to
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];
            Enemy *enemy = enemies[j];

            if (checkCollision(rocket->getSprite(), enemy->getSprite()))
            {
                //hitSound.play();
                score++;
                std::string finalScore = "Score: " + std::to_string(score);
                scoreText.setString(finalScore);
                sf::FloatRect scoreBounds = scoreText.getGlobalBounds();
                scoreText.setOrigin(scoreBounds.width / 2, scoreBounds.height / 2);
                scoreText.setPosition(viewSize.x * 0.5f, viewSize.y * 0.10f);



                rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j);

                delete(rocket);
                delete(enemy);
                if (score % 5 == 0) levelUp();
                printf("rocket intersects with enemy \n");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have stored the enemy and rocket objects in vectors:

```
    std::vector <Enemy*> enemies;
    std::vector <Rocket*> rockets;
```

Here's my entire update function if that helps:

```
void update(float dt)
{
    hero.update(dt);

    currentTime += dt;
    if (currentTime >= prevTime + 1.125f)
    {
        spawnEnemy();
        prevTime = currentTime;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        Enemy *enemy = enemies[i];
        enemy->update(dt);

        if (enemy->getSprite().getPosition().x < 0)
        {
            enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
            delete(enemy);
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverSound.play();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++)
    {
        Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];

        rocket->update(dt);

        if (rocket->getSprite().getPosition().x > viewSize.x)
        {
            rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
            delete(rocket);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            Rocket *rocket = rockets[i];
            Enemy *enemy = enemies[j];

            if (checkCollision(rocket->getSprite(), enemy->getSprite()))
            {
            //hitSound.play();
                score++;
                std::string finalScore = "Score: " + std::to_string(score);
                scoreText.setString(finalScore);
                sf::FloatRect scoreBounds = scoreText.getGlobalBounds();
                scoreText.setOrigin(scoreBounds.width / 2, scoreBounds.height / 2);
                scoreText.setPosition(viewSize.x * 0.5f, viewSize.y * 0.10f);



                rockets.erase(rockets.begin() + i);
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j);

                delete(rocket);
                delete(enemy);
                if (score % 5 == 0) levelUp();
                printf("rocket intersects with enemy \n");
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        Enemy *enemy = enemies[i];

        if (checkCollision(enemy->getSprite(), hero.getSprite()))
        {
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverSound.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run it through the debugger? Also, don't use pointers inside containers, if you must have persisting iterators use shared_ptr

Comment: This is a clear-cut job for a debugger.

Comment: You can fix the error, debugging your code line by line and find the place where your index variable goes out of bounds.

Comment: If you have 1 rocket and 3 enemies, what happens to the rocket vector after the first enemy collides with the rocket?

Comment: "How to fix 'Expression: vector subscript out of range' error" - Easy: Don't access out of range of your container.

Comment: You musn't erase  elements from vector in the loop. You should mark them as objects scheldued for remove and remove them later, e.g. using stl: 
std::remove_if

Comment: what everybody else said...but if you are deleting it, you should start at the end, not at the beginning

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove elements from a vector as you iterate over it. You're removing elements but not properly adjusting i and j so you end up out of bounds with your indices.

Comment: But then I don't understand why the error doesn't show up when there are only 2 enemies on screen. Why does it only happen when there are 3 or more enemies on screen at the same time?

Comment: It is undefined behavior. Deleting an object doesn't wipe the memory it just allows the program to reclaim it. The data could be valid even after you delete it. One other thing I noticed is that when a rocket collides you delete it but you continue to loop over the other enemies and check if the rocket has collided with them. It creates a scenario where you will potentially delete the rocket twice. This is definitely invalid behavior.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer